# Filling a chain link fence end post with concrete

Tags: fence

I have a 6 foot chain link fence. The end posts that come up to my house are set in concrete and do not move at the base but they still tend to wobble a bit near the top because of the height. I would like to know if filling the post up with concrete you be a good way to add more stability.

Comment: Can you tell if the post is bending, or if the footing is moving?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be bending on it's own just when I grab it  near the top it seems to bend fairly easily compared to other 4' fence I have. The footing seems stable.

Comment: Filling the post with concrete should prevent the post from bending, but if it's the footing that's moving you won't see any benefit.

Answer (score 2):

That wont solve the problem.  The best way to make a 'solid' fence post is to bury more into the ground.

Putting a cement ball at the bottom is not the best solution and filling the hollow cavity will do nothing to help